# EUnit view failed test results in detail

Tags: erlang, assert, eunit

I am not an expert in `EUnit` and I mainly use `?assert_(fun1(Args) == Result)` to test all the functions in my Erlang code (I define `Result` in the `_tests` module).

But in case a test fails it does not show what `fun1` has actually returned.

Instead, it says something like "It should be true, but was false".

How can I make `EUnit` to show in its output what `fun1(Args)` has actually returned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `?assertEqual(Expect, Expr)` macro:

```
?assertEqual(Result, fun1(Args))
```

For more ?assert macros, check [eunit docs](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/eunit/chapter.html)

Comment: Also, check out this hidden treasure of eunit examples:
[github.com/richcarl/eunit/](https://github.com/richcarl/eunit/blob/master/examples/eunit_examples.erl)

I often use it as a reference when writing eunit tests.